# jquery get element's id

Tags: jquery, search

I have this code:

```
var deEdit = $("#opsEdit a, h1");

deEdit.live("click", function(){
 $.ajax({ url: "codigo/file.php?v1=" + this.id + "&v2=" + HOW DO I GET THE H1 ELEMENT'S ID???,
 cache: false,
     success: function(respuesta){
    $("#showData").html(respuesta); 
 }
   });
})
```

and that's it.... how do I get the H1 element's ID? I know the A's ID but what about the H1's ID?, I tried this.next().id but didn't work, any help here would be very appreciated.

Comment: You don't, not like that at least. The event fires whenever you click an `a` tag that is a child of `opsEdit` OR any `h1` tag. You can't click one thing and get the id of the other unless you know where it is already. You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: `this.id` holds the `h1`s idea if you click on an `h1`.

Comment: If it will be the `.next()` element, you probably want `.next().get().id` or `.next().prop('id')` instead.

Comment: Ok, I added this line inside the live event function: var elId = $("#opsEdit").find('h1').id; but I get "undefined"

Comment: what I did was to use the class of the a element to put my variable there, it worked for me

Comment: what I never understood was.. how come I got -2 votes on my question?? was it too dumb??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elId = $('#opsEdit h1').attr('id');
```